# Find a closed-form solution to the following summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I am solving a summation that appears in a paper, it claims that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n+k}z^n=\bigg(\frac{4z}{(1+\sqrt{1-4z})^2}\bigg)^k$$
I found this identity [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html) in equation (66)
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n+k}{n}z^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n+k}{n}z^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n+k}{n+k}z^n =\bigg(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\bigg)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}$$
I didn't found the paper that has the proof of the identity above, but I notice that
$$\binom{2n}{n+k}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{2n+j}{n+k-1}=\binom{2n+k}{n+k}$$
Therefore we obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n+k}z^n=\bigg(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\bigg)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}-1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{2n+j}{n+k-1}z^n$$
Yet I have no idea for the last summation above, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A side note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n+k}z^n=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n+k}z^n$ and in the context $k\geq1$, not too sure if these helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use an approach based upon the *[Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)* and prove for $k$ being a non-negative integer
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n+k}{n}z^n=\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\qquad\qquad |z|<\frac{1}{4}}
\end{align*}

We follow thereby the paper *[Lagrange Inversion: when and how](http://local.disia.unifi.it/merlini/papers/LagrangeInversion.pdf)* by R. Sprugnoli etal. We consider the generating function
\begin{align*}
F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n+k}{n}z^n
\end{align*}
and apply formula (G6) from the paper. The formula (G6) tells us that if there are functions $A(u)$ and $\phi(u)$, so that the coefficient $a_n$ admits a representation
\begin{align*}
a_n=[u^n]A(u)\phi(u)^n
\end{align*}
where $[u^n]$ denotes the coefficient of $u^n$ of a series, then the following is valid:
\begin{align*}
F(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[u^n]A(u)\phi(u)^nz^n\\
&=\left.\frac{A(u)}{1-z\phi^{\prime}(u)}\right|_{u=z\phi(u)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F(z)}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n+k}{n}z^n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty[u^n](1+u)^{2n+k}z^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\left.\frac{(1+u)^k}{1-z\,\frac{d}{du}(1+u)^2}\right|_{u=z(1+u)^2}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{(1+u)^k}{1-\frac{u}{(1+u)^2}\cdot 2(1+u)}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{(1+u)^{k+1}}{1-u}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)^{k+1}}{2-\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}}\tag{6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of a series. We observe we can apply the Lagrange Inversion theorem with $A(u)=(1+u)^k$ and $\phi(u)=(1+u)^2$.
- In (3) we use formula (1) with $A$ and $\phi$ as stated in the comment above.
- In (4) we substitute $z=\frac{u}{1+u}$ and do the derivation.
- In (5) we simplify the expression.
- In (6) we recall $u=z(1+u)^2$ which is a quadratic equation in $u=u(z)$. We calculate
  \begin{align*}
  u(z)&=\frac{1}{2z}\left(1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)\\
  &=\frac{1}{2z}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)-1\\
  &=\frac{1}{2z}\,\frac{1-(1-4z)}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}-1\\
  &=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}-1
  \end{align*}
  and take the solution with the minus sign, since this one can be expanded as generating function.
- In (7) we make again some simplifications to obtain the wanted form.

> **Note:** The relationship with OPs first stated formula is given via
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n+k}z^n}
> &=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n}{n+k}z^n\tag{8}\\
> &=\sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n}{n-k}z^n\tag{9}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n+2k}{n}z^{n+k}\tag{10}\\
> &=z^k\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)^{2k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\tag{11}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\frac{4z}{\left(1+\sqrt{1-4z}\right)^2}\right)^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (8) we start the right-hand side with index $n=k$, since $\binom{2n}{n+k}=0$ if $n<k$.
- In (9) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (10) we shift the index to start with $n=0$ again.
- In (11) we use the identity (7) from above with $k\to 2k$ and make finally some simplifications.

Comment: It seems that we both answered this question at the cited link below.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Yes, you're right. I've adapted my answer from there.

Comment: Great solution from both of you! Thank you for the help and i appreciate it! P.S. I would have a thorough look at the solution later.

Comment: @求石莫得: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The identity

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} {2n+k\choose n} z^n
= \left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}} \right)^k
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}
= Q_k(z)$$

can also be proved with the Cauchy Coefficient Formula, radius of
convergence is the  distance to the nearest singularity which is at
$1/4.$

We obtain

$$[z^n] Q_k(z) =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}
\left(\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}} \right)^k
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} \; dz.$$

Now we put $w=\sqrt{1-4z}$ with the branch cut on $[1/4,\infty)$
(principal branch of the logarithm) so that we have
analyticity in a neighborhood of the origin and $dw = -2
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} \; dz$. With $\sqrt{1-4z} = 1-2z-\cdots$ the image
of $|z|=\varepsilon$ makes  one turn around $w=1$ plus lower order
fluctuations so that it may  be deformed to a small circle and we get
with $z=(1-w^2)/4$

$$- \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{4^{n+1}}{(1-w^2)^{n+1}}
\left(\frac{2}{1+w} \right)^k \; dw
\\ = - \frac{2^{2n+k+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1+w)^{n+1+k}} \; dw
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n\times 2^{n}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1+(w-1)/2)^{n+1+k}} \; dw$$

This yields by the Cauchy Residue Theorem

$$(-1)^n 2^n \times (-1)^n \frac{1}{2^n} {n+n+k\choose n}
= {2n+k\choose n}$$

as claimed.

**Remark.** This identity and the proof appeared at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025969/) from which it may be obtained by a straightforward square root manipulation.

Comment: Nice to also see the residue theorem. (+1)

Comment: Thanks, it is a nice technique.